# Uploaded images do not show on localhost

Tags: uploads

I'm working with Wordpress 3.3.1 on a local installation. I've uploaded an image file and it doesn't show up.

The base directory is a symbolic link `/var/www/wordpress/` that leads to `/usr/share/wordpress/`

The file exists here:
`/srv/www/wp-uploads/localhost/2013/01/Logo.png`

Wordpress thinks the file is here:
`http://localhost/wordpress/2013/01/Logo.png` (Apache gives 404)

How can I configure Apache or Wordpress to get the correct file?

I'm confused because `/srv/www/localhost/` contains the Wordpress files (as well).

Also, I've found questions related to `wp-content/uploads` but this directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Without knowing more about your setup, I don't think anyone could be much help. If you are running your WP blog locally using VirtualBox, I have some [notes here](http://www.aahank.com/2012/12/setup-test-server-with-dummy.html).

Comment: Are these files you uploaded using the WP uploader? Are you saying that the uploads are working, but not displaying the files afterwards?

Comment: @totels, yes, the uploads are working, but the files are placed where Apache doesn't find them.

Comment: @its_me, yes, I'm running VirtualBox, I'll take a look at your notes. Thanks.

Comment: @its_me, I've read your piece, but I'm only interested in localhost. This is a sandbox proyect to get my design sorted out. Once I'm done, I'll put it on the hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your permissions and / or ownership on `/usr/share/wordpress/` could be wrong. Try setting this directory to 777 and CHOWN the owner to Apache (on Ubuntu it runs as user www-data).

If WordPress was unzipped/expanded in `/usr/share/wordpress` you would have a folder `wp-content` - and the /uploads folder should be created in there (assuming permissions etc are right).

You also mention `/srv/www/wp-uploads/localhost/` and `/srv/www/localhost/`  -- so maybe you were changing your VHOST files too? Have you enabled mod-rewrite or anything different?

Comment: I have all the dirs and files as www-data and with 755 at least. I'm not aware of touching VHOST files. I did add mod-rewrite to an Apache file, but that was way after having the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a symbolic link in the /var/www/ directory.

`ln -s /srv/www/wp-uploads/localhost/ wp-uploads`

This is probably an ugly hack and there must be something wrong with the Apache configuration, but it works for the Sandbox.